# Data Warehouse - Multidimensional Model - Fact Table is Smaller than Dimension Table

Tags: ssas, data-modeling, data-warehouse, dimensional-modeling, fact-table

I am working on data warehouse project where customer dimension table is larger than a fact table. Dimension and Fact tables are created from CRM system.

The fact table monitors activities such as letter is sent to a customer or customer calls for assistance. Half of customers have no activities and remaining customers have very few activities; most of customers who have activities have a single activity.

I am not sure if star schema is the best solution for project. Have you worked on similar projects & what was the solution.

Comment: The design seems correct but the situation you describe is weird. However, I don't know your customer's business. Is it there usually only one letter sent to a customer or one phone call during the entire cooperation?

Comment: Usually fact tables store many more encounters with customers, like sales transactions.  In your case, a more straightforward normalized relational database may perform better.  You'd have to test both the star schema and the normalized schema to be sure.

Comment: Nothing wrong with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If many of the dimension members are not related to the facts at all. I would sugest to filter unused dimension members during the ETL process.

So you do a

```
     SELECT Customer_ID, Name FROM DIL.Customers 
       WHERE Customer_ID IS IN 
       (SELECT Customer_ID FROM DIL.Calls)
```